# One hot encoding of a string in column in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a column 'description' and I would like to make a one hot encoding that includes the word count of the words in the description

```
    description
0   test words that describe things
1   more and more words here
2   things test
```

Desired output

```
    test   words  that describe things more  here  and
0   1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
1   0.0    1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    2.0   1.0   1.0
2   1.0    0.0    0.0    0.0    1.0    0.0   0.0   0.0
```

The current solution I have is:

```py
one_hot = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.description).str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts(), axis=1)
```

This gets very slow (2.6 ms per row) on a large dataset (130K rows) and I was wondering if there was a better solution.
I would also like to remove words that show up in only one entry.

```
    test   words  things
0   1.0    1.0    1.0
1   0.0    1.0    0.0
2   1.0    0.0    1.0
```

Comment: That's a bit over twice as fast! Awesome, how does this work?

Comment: Ahh it also doesn't do word count, but I think I can work around that

Comment: @anky_91 Just out of curiosity, why not `df['description'].str.get_dummies(sep=" ")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, for counts , you can do a `groupby+sum` on `axis=1` after `get_dummies`

```
final = (pd.get_dummies(df['description'].str.split(expand=True))
         .groupby(lambda x: x.split('_')[-1],axis=1).sum())
```

Or with apply(slower):

```
df['description'].str.split(expand=True).apply(pd.value_counts,axis=1).fillna(0)
```

---

```
   and  describe  here  more  test  that  things  words
0    0         1     0     0     1     1       1      1
1    1         0     1     2     0     0       0      1
2    0         0     0     0     1     0       1      0
```